# htaccess not working in my local host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I will try to be as clear as possible:
the htaccess file is located in

```
http://localhost:8080/trevision/.htaccess
```

below is whats included in htacesss

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/$ /searchPage.php
```

essentially what this is trying to do redefine the default page on the search folder from index to searchPage.php
the searchPage is found in

```
http://localhost:8080/trevision/search/searchPage.php
```

I have already checked httpd.conf and its set to `AllowOverride All` everwhere

Any help would be appreciated.

For any clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your rule's target to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/$ search/searchPage.php [L]
```

Since the htaccess file is in `/trevision/`, that's where all relative paths will start from. When someone goes to `/trevision/search/` the rule will match and get rewritten to `/trevision/search/searchPage.php`.

Alternatively, you can try adding in the  htaccess file in the `search` folder:

```
DirectoryIndex searchPage.php
```

Comment: @user3907211 it stops the rewrite engine from executing any further rules. Is a good habit to use in the event that you end up adding more rules to the htaccess file.

Comment: You could also add NC like so `[L,NC]` to make it non-case-sensitive so if someone types SEARCH your rule will be applied as well.

Comment: thank for the comments. it may seem then the problem goes far  beyond the code as it just shows me the list of pages available when you go to search/ as it has no index. I am using xampp